# Override DHCP hostname on RHEL5/CentOS/Amazon Linux

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, dhcp, rhel5, linux-networking

I'm running Amazon Linux (based on RHEL5) on EC2.

I have my own domain name pointing to the instance's elastic IP. Amazon auto-assigns the instance a generic (and not visible on the Internet) hostname via DHCP.

This internal-only hostname breaks sending email since the SMTP server wants to see a real (and public) hostname. I can fix email by manually running the "hostname" command to set the real public hostname.

I have set HOSTNAME in /etc/sysconfig/network but the DHCP hostname seems to override this.

Is there a good/correct way to set my hostname and always ignore what DHCP has to say about it, while still using DHCP otherwise?

I can think of lots of kludgy stuff to do (run a script that undoes what DHCP does, or whatever) but wondering if there's an actual config setting somewhere to force the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike's answer sounds better and will likely work, but if it gives you trouble, you can always use a sledgehammer.  :)

Add

```
/bin/hostname HOSTNAME
```

To

```
/etc/rc.local
```

:)

Comment: Went with the sledge for now. Was hoping to avoid it and do things the "right way" but the "working way" is always plan B ;-)

Comment: Hmm. Over time it turns out that the sledge fails, because on re-dhcp (which EC2 servers appear to do occasionally), the hostname gets lost again.

Comment: yup, not a good solution, on re-leasing this will go to the toilet.

Answer (score 8):

Try this.. Edit

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

Then add

```
DHCP_HOSTNAME=host.domain.com
```

See if that clears it up.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but it doesn't seem to work on the Amazon Linux image (maybe it was added post-RHEL5?)

Comment: you know, this may work. I was doing something super stupid (I have a whole setup to apply config patches to a pristine unmodified AMI ... but it applies them after the network is up).

Answer (score 5):

For Centos 6 and therefore Redhat 6 you will continually lose whatever hostname you want your host to be known as locally, each time you get a new IP or reboot, while using DHCP.
(Redhat 5 / Centos 5 info also below)

(which can be a pain if you script backups or similar, relying on a static hostname)

If you use dhclient and continually have your desired localhostname overwritten (forgotten) by the DHCP provided hostname, read on.

To force a local hostname (and still let DHCP give you whatever IP it wants) you need to modify (or create) the file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf`.

(replace the string eth0 with whatever network interface you are getting your hostname overwritten by, eth0 works for most)

For my setup, this simple filecontent works:

```
interface "eth0"  
   {    
     supersede host-name "myworkbox";  
   }
```

and I save to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf`.

If you have Redhat 5 / Centos 5, try doing the same, but file location should be `/etc/dhclient-eth0.conf`.

You will see why this occurs by viewing the section that references 
`dhclient-${DEVICE}.conf` in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup`

If you need to get a particular ip address, you need to review the manpage for dhclient.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work on CentOS7 (on AWS, with SELinux enabled, even with correct contexts). :-(

Answer (score 4):

For the CentOS 7 AMI, set a static hostname by commenting out the lines:

```
- set_hostname
- update_hostname
```

in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`. The comment character for YAML is `#`.

This is in addition to setting the hostname normally.

Comment: You can also add `preserve_hostname: true` in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
PEERDNS="no"
```

in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX (tested on CentOS 6)

Comment: Peer dns is to enable(default) or disable /etc/resolv.conf update.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf addition (for AWS AMI (CentOS)) with contents:

```
interface "eth0"  
{    
  supersede host-name "myworkbox";  
}
```

seemed to work just fine (if using dhcp, of course). Thanks!